# write.table converting NaNs to NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
a = data.frame("a"=c(1,2,3,NA,NaN,6),"b"=c(NA,NA,NaN,1,2,3),"c"=c(1,2,NA,NA,5,6))
```

I am writing it to a file

```
write.table(a,file="t.txt",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

Its converting "NaN" to "NA". I want to retain the original values. How can I do that?
I want to keep NaN and NA in my t.txt. But I get all NA in my t.txt

Comment: We don't know what `a` is and the function you've shown shouldn't produce any `NaN` values.  However, you can pass the `na=...` argument to specify what you want missing values to look like.

Comment: I have edited the question. It was copy paste error.

Comment: a hack would be to convert NaN to "NaN" and then afterwards (when reading in the file) convert "NaN" to NaN and the column with `as.numeric(x)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way to do it directly, but you can always convert the columns to character, then write it (since you're using `quote=FALSE`).

```
> a[] <- lapply(a, as.character)
> write.table(a,file="t.txt",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep="\t")
> str(read.table("t.txt",header=TRUE))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 NA NaN 6
 $ b: num  NA NA NaN 1 2 3
 $ c: int  1 2 NA NA 5 6
```

Comment: Why is the `[]` there, if I may ask this off-topic question?

Comment: @Dualinity: so `a` will remain a `data.frame`, since `lapply` returns a list.